# basic rules logarithm of exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am looking for proof of the basic rules of logarithm. I can prove all basic rules except this $$\log_ab^y=y\log_ab$$
how to get this rule using definition of logarithm.

Comment: What definition? There are several equivalent definitions. Most either have it as the inverse exponential function or $\int_1^x\frac{1}{x}dx$

Comment: @CBenni:  I expect it's just this definition: "$z = \log_a b$ if $a^z = b$".

Comment: @TaraB well that might be the definition, but I know a lot of professors choose another definition for various (or no) reasons.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just meant that I expect that in this case what I said is the relevant definition (I was the one who 'upvoted' your comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\log_ab=m\iff a^m=b$

So, $\log_ab^y=n\iff a^n=b^y=(a^m)^y=a^{my}\implies n=my$ if $a\ne0,1$

So, $\log_ab^y=n=my=y\log_ab$

Answer (score 2):

Just check that
$$
a^{y \log_{a}(b)}
=
a^{\log_{a}(b) y}
=
\left(a^{\log_{a}(b)}\right)^{y}
=
b^{y}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know, or have proven that $\log_a(xy) = \log_a x + \log_z y$
We use this to prove:

$$\log_ab^y= \log_a \underbrace{(b \cdot b \cdot ...\cdot b)}_{\large y \; times}$$
$$\iff \log_a b^y = \underbrace{\log_a b + \log_a b + \cdots + \log_z b}_{\large y \;\;times}$$
$$ \iff \log_ab^y = y\log_z b$$

Else: by definition only

$$a^{y \log_{a}(b)}= a^{\log_{a}(b) y}=\left(a^{\log_{a}(b)}\right)^{y}=b^{y}.$$

Comment: what if $y\notin \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @CBenni That's why I included the "else"...by definition...

Answer (score 0):

$b=a^{\log_a(b)}$ so $$b^y=(a^{\log_a(b)})^y$$ and by $$(p^m)^n=p^{m\cdot n}$$ you get $$b^y=a^{y\cdot\log_a(b)}$$ taking $\log_a$ on both sides gives:
$$\log_a(b^y)=\log_a(a^{y\cdot\log_a(b)}$$ which by the definition $\log_p(p^m)=m$ goes to:
$$\log_a(b^y)=y\cdot\log_a(b)$$
QED